# Haskell prime numbers

Tags: haskell, primes

I want to generate infinite prime numbers but in some case it's stopping without complete the infinite list

here is my attempt:

```
Primeach :: [Int]

Primeach = [n | n <- [2..] , product [1..n-1] `rem` n == n-1]
```

Comment: Please post the actual code you are using. The code you have provided has at least one syntax error and could not possibly produce one prime let alone 34 of them.  Also, if you are discussing performance then please include the way you are compiling and/or running the code presented.

Comment: Also, 35 is not prime so you should think about this algorithm some and why it produces 35... then fix the algorithm.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson It actually works fairly well, if only you disregard the obvious capitalization error.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Oh I'm well aware of the fix, but it proves the code presented is not the code the asker ran.  Copy and pasting code can save all potential answerers much time and clear up lots of confusion. Best not to start answering without a clear problem.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson True. There are actually several less trivial problems with this question, for instance it is unclear whether number 35 is produced or only 35 numbers are produced. But I want to point out that the algorithm described by this _Haskell-like pseudo code_ actually produces prime numbers, albeit not very quickly.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience actulally the code compile and run but after maybe 5 numbers it's stop.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem [Actually](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10!+mod+11) it's correct(because [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)). But the problem is because he's using `Int`s and the product overflows past a certain number (for 64-bit systems it overflows at n=22). Trying to formulate an answer to clearly explain it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem of not finding primes larger than 19 stems from the line

```
primeach :: [Int]
```

This is because you have to calculate `product [1..n-1]` for those numbers. This overflows when `n >= 22`, since `Int` is (usually) a 64-bit number under the hood in 64-bit systems (it's guaranteed to have at least 30 bits), in 32-bit systems with 32-bit `Int` it will overflow at `n >= 14`.
Since it overflows, your are no longer taking the correct remainder anymore.
For example, with 64-bit signed integers, we have for `n=23` (which is prime):

```
Prelude> product [1..22]
1124000727777607680000 :: Integer
Prelude> product [1..22] :: Int
-1250660718674968576 :: Int
Prelude> product [1..22] `rem` 23
22 :: Integer
Prelude> product [1..22] `rem` 23 :: Int
-22 :: Int
```

As you can see, this no longer works because of the overflow.
Another example would be `n=29` which is also prime:

```
Prelude> product [1..28]
304888344611713860501504000000 :: Integer
Prelude> product [1..28] :: Int
-5968160532966932480 :: Int
Prelude> product [1..28] `rem` 29
28 :: Integer
Prelude> product [1..28] `rem` 29 :: Int
-27 :: Int
```

So this shows that it's not even a simple sign flip.

You have 2 options:

- If you want to use this algorithm, switch to `Integer`s (Even if only for the `product` calculation), those will never overflow:

  ```
  primeach :: [Int]
  primeach = [fromInteger n | n <- [2..] , product [1..n-1] `rem` n == n-1]
  ```
- Use a different algorithm, or consider using an existing package for primes.